# Apllication architecure 3 tiers or 4 tiers?

Tags: rest, spring-boot, architecture

I am preparing my 
19/5000
last study's project, and now I am disturbed and I can not tell if my application is 3 or 4 tiers.

In this application I use Spring Boot (Back-end) and a private framework created by the company (Front-end).
In fact, I thought too much and I arrived since in the execution of my project I use a single server (apache tomcat). my architecture is 3 tiers

Comment: if you are using mvc architecture then 3 tiers

Comment: Guessing those "thirds" were supposed to be "tiers"

Answer (score 0):

For me, no matter how many layers we use. It shouldn't be a blocking question when developing software architecture. The only important thing is to decouple Policies from details applying the DIP (Dependency Inversion Principle) when coding your classes.
So don't bother with this kind of question, just apply SOLID principles.